# Why do ashkenazi jews skip a part of the Aleinu Leshabeach?

Tags: tefilla, aleinu-leshabeiach

I'm an ashkenazi jew and have always wondered why do we skip this sentence in the first paragraph of the Aleinu. The sentence says something like: "We do not pray to false gods".I know it got something to do with the inquisition but that's as far as I know.

Comment: http://www.kayj.net/en/forum/nusach/413-oleinu-qshehem-mishtachavimq-etc. http://www.ottmall.com/mj_ht_arch/v33/mj_v33i61.html#CTI

Comment: I think you are referring to a phrase that roughly translates to "For they bow down to vanity and nothingness and pray to gods that cannot provide them salvation". Is that it?

Comment: I'm an Ashkenazi Jew and I don't skip that line.

Comment: yes, I believe you are right, but why?